# How to remove dresser drawers

Tags: drawers

I know there are several different types of drawer removal mechanisms. (Not sure on the names so feel free to edit)

1. Free rolling. 
   These open by simply rolling the drawer fully out and lifting the wheels on the back of the drawer up off the track and then pulling them out.
2. In track.
   These drawers can be removed by rolling the drawer fully out and lifting the two levers on the inside of the track. A [YouTube video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=3y1cqAMKhOo) clearly shows this.
3. In track, no levers.
   No clue how to open this. 
   [image: photo of track]

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out. For cheaper drawers, there is a single screw on the inside of the drawer. Remove that screw from both sides to detach the drawer from the metal sliders on each side.

Comment: very helpful. Would add that when re attaching - you need to line up the track with the screw hole to be able to re-screw in the screw.

Comment: Good job. I've never seen that type before, thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

Another type of drawer has metal guide bar on the outside edge of the bottom of each drawer held in place with two small screws and kept straight with an alignment pin. I had to unscrew both screws on both sides, slightly lift the drawer up to clear an alignment pin and the drawer was free to remove.

When replacing, there were two notches on the back of the drawer that had to line up with a retaining tab on the rear of the drawer slide -- once those tabs were in place, the alignment pin fit back in the hole and all that was left was to put the 4 screws back in place.